# at command gives output error

Tags: command-line, output

When running the at command on Ubuntu 18, What I noticed is that I can run it as root, but not as root results in an Output Error as follows:

```
root@myserver3:~/# at now
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
at> /bin/echo "this is root" > /tmp/at.out.txt
at> <EOT>
job 3 at Thu Jun  4 19:15:00 2020
root@myserver3:~/# cat /tmp/at.out.txt
this is root
root@myserver3:~/# exit
exit
rich@myserver3:~/$ at now
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
at> /bin/echo "This is me" > /tmp/at.out.me.txt
at> <EOT>
at: Output error
rich@myserver3:~/$ cat /tmp/at.out.me.txt
cat: /tmp/at.out.me.txt: No such file or directory
```

I've reinstalled at, I checked the file permissions of /var/spool/cron:

```
drwx-wx--T 2 root   crontab 4.0K Jun  4 19:06 crontabs
drwxr-xr-x 5 root   root    4.0K Jun  5 15:27 .
drwxrwx--T 2 daemon daemon  4.0K Jun  5 15:28 atspool
drwxrwx--T 2 daemon daemon  4.0K Jun  5 15:28 atjob
```

I've checked /etc/at.deny and /etc/at.allow.  They look the same as they do on servers where this command works just fine.

To be sure I removed /etc/at.allow /etc/at.deny, then removed /var/spool/cron/atjobs and /var/spool/cron/atspool. Then I reinstalled with apt-get install --reinstall at.  The files returned and have the same permissions / content as they do on my working servers.

At (haha) a loss as to what is wrong here.

```
# ls -alhrt /usr/bin/at
-rwsr-sr-x 1 daemon daemon 51K Jan 14  2016 /usr/bin/at
```

Comment: It's a longshot, but I wonder if the filesystem is essentially full, but root is still allowed to write to the spool because of reserved blocks?